# Django 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_prefetch_related_lookups' disappears after reboot

Tags: django

I am having an intermittent issue with my Django web app where the error above appears every few days on one of my forms. Restarting the webserver resolves the issue and I am at a loss of what is going on. I have other views with similar code that don't have the same problem.

I am using django.db.backends.sqlite3 as the database.

The form basically collects a bunch of data and on submission goes to another page to generate a PDF using the values entered. It's failing trying to bring up the form.

views.py

```
def generate_correspondence_form(request, file_id):
    
    file = File.objects.get(id=file_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        placeholderform = CorrespondencePlaceholderForm(request.POST)
        correspondenceform = GenerateCorrespondenceForm(request.POST)
        if correspondenceform.is_valid() and placeholderform.is_valid():
            request.session['a'] = list(placeholderform.cleaned_data.get('a').values('id'))
            request.session['b'] = list(correspondenceform.cleaned_data.get('b').values('id'))
            request.session['c'] = correspondenceform.cleaned_data.get('c')
            request.session['d'] = correspondenceform.cleaned_data.get('d').id
            request.session['e'] = correspondenceform.cleaned_data.get('e')
            request.session['f'] = correspondenceform.cleaned_data.get('f')
            request.session['g'] = correspondenceform.cleaned_data.get('g')
            request.session['h'] = correspondenceform.cleaned_data.get('h')
            request.session['i'] = correspondenceform.cleaned_data.get('i')
            if correspondenceform.cleaned_data.get('j'):
                request.session['j'] = correspondenceform.cleaned_data.get('j').id
            if request.POST.get('submit_ashtml'):
                url = f"{reverse('logs:generate_correspondence', kwargs={'file_id': file_id})}?as=html"
                return redirect(url)
            else:
                return redirect('logs:generate_correspondence', file_id=file_id)
        
    else:
        placeholderform = CorrespondencePlaceholderForm()
        correspondenceform = GenerateCorrespondenceForm()
        placeholderform.fields['a'].queryset = A.objects.filter(target__file=file)
        correspondenceform.fields['b'].queryset = B.objects.filter(file=file)
    context = {'correspondenceform': correspondenceform, 'placeholderform': placeholderform, 'file': file}
    return render(request, 'logs/generatecorrespondenceform.html', context)
```

EDIT: I will post the full traceback the next time it occurs. I can't reproduce it on demand.

Comment: Please edit your post and add the **Full Error Traceback**

Comment: I will post the full traceback the next time it occurs. I can't reproduce it on demand.

Comment: Okey no problem.